# Можно ли говорить "очень грандиозные планы"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексическая-сочетаемость

Вчера в нашей области назначили нового министра образования, и она в своем первом интервью заявила: "У нас очень грандиозные планы".
Мне кажется, что "очень" и "грандиозно" неупотребимы вместе.
А как вы думаете?

Answer (score 3):

Вы правы, так говорить нельзя. В слове "грандиозная" уже есть значение слова ОЧЕНЬ.

Comment: Спасибо Вам.

Comment: А моэжно ли сказать:"достаточно грандиозные планы"? (Человек стеснительный и не хочет хвастаться заранее, но хочет обратить внимание на масштабность предложенных мероприятий)

Answer (score 1):

Министру образования на людях так говорить, конечно, не стоит, если это не ирония. 
"Очень" (как и "достаточно", "слишком" и т.п.) передает *степень качества*, выражаемого прилагательным, т.е. строго по норме сочетается только с качественными прилагательными. А "грандиозный" - прилагательное пока еще относительное (впрочем - *см. ниже*). 
Но вся штука в том, что в современном разговорном стиле вообще любое прилагательное (вплоть до притяжательных!) приобретает в той или иной степени черты качественного. 
Смотрите, сказать "более грандиозный" вполне возможно, краткая форма (которая "по учебнику" отсутствует у относительных прилагательных) наличествует: "планы грандиозны"... С наречием "слишком" тоже сочетается без проблем. 
Так что в таком случае мечтает планам быть *очень* грандиозными? Только стилистика - но это уже личное дело "министерства культуры".

(+)

Во как... Оказывается, если верить некоторым источникам, теперь прилагательные относят к качественным при наличии *хотя бы одного из признаков* из известного характеристического списка *качественного прилагательного* (возможность образования наречия, отвлеченного существительного, наличие сравнительной степени, кратной формы и т.д.), а вовсе не их совокупности. Но тогда это только подчеркивает основную мысль... Я не буду править, за исключением этой оговорки про отнесении к качественным прилагательным все сказанное - верно.